# How to Integrate Java+Android help to Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to **Java** & **Android**, i want to have **Java** & **Android** **help** in **Eclipse** so when i select phrase and press **F1**, it show me detail and usage of that command, something like **MSDN** offline help in **Visual Studio**.

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: MSDN of "Android" could be [Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html), it isn't offline tho, but it can help you so much to learn what do each function.

Comment: You have the Java help within the jdk. Download the javadoc jar for each library to have it available offline. When you're there, download the source jar as well. It can be even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Put the mouse pointer over the class and you will get contextual help

[image]

F2 makes the help dialog focus, Press the javadoc button and it will show in the javadoc view

[image]

Updated :
When yous install the Android SDK and choose to install source, what described above comes out of the box, for general Java code, you will have to attach javacode or sourcecode : Right click the jar file -> properties -> select java source attachment or javadoc location. Note that it's always provided in a seperate zip download from the jar download web site

For the illustrated sample, download is found in the source section here :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

[image]

Comment: When yous install the Android SDK and choose to install source, what described above come out of the box, for general Java code, you will have to attach javacode or sourcecode : Right click the jar file -> properties -> select java source attachment or javadoc location. Note that it's always provided in a seperate zip download from the jar download web site